# Declarative dojox.grid.datagrid's header has onclick event?

Tags: javascript, datagrid, dojo, dojox.grid.datagrid

- Is it possible to have onclick in dojox.grid.datagrid's header.
- I tried calling a function in header's onclick.. but it doesn't work.

  ```
  <div class="claro" id="cvsd" name="dataGrid" onclick="getConnect('inner__cvsd');setWidgetproperty(this.id,'xy','inner__cvsd');" ondblclick="editCustomGrid(this.id)" onmouseup="setDocStyle(this.id)" style="height: 200px; left: 44px; position: absolute; top: 114px; width: 950px;">
   <table class="claro" dojotype="dojox.grid.DataGrid" id="inner__cvsd" rowselector="10px" style="height: 180px; width: 400px;">
        <thead>
             <tr>
                  <th field="Column1" id="Column1_2" width="100px" onclick="getConnect();">
                      Column1
                  </th>
             </tr>
        </thead>
   </table>
   <input id="hidden__cvsd" name="dataGrid" style="display:none;" type="hidden">
  ```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's an event called `onHeaderCellClick` which will probably do the job. If you need to get more information about events and such things I recommend reading the [API Documentation](http://dojotoolkit.org/api/1.7/dojox/grid/DataGrid).
I wrote an example JSFiddle (grid is created programmatically, but you can do that declarative too) which you can find [here](http://jsfiddle.net/TMm7y/).

The code that I use to call the event is the following:

```
onHeaderCellClick: function() {
    console.log("Header clicked");  
},
```

But of course, you can change this with whatever you like.

Comment: its working.. any possibility to achieve this in declarative way? i mean onclick event inside <th>

Comment: I assume you're using dojo 1.6, so you can do this by adding the attribute `onHeaderCellClick` to your `<table>`. For example `onHeaderCellClick="test"` will call function `test()`.

Comment: So to make it clear, it's not the onclick event, but the onHeaderCellClick event ;)

Comment: @DimitriM [Can we change the one header column in data grid to button](http://stackoverflow.com/q/20918759/1036917)?