# How to create a dojo data grid with one of column being a button in header row?

Tags: javascript, grid, dojo, dojox.grid.datagrid

I have a dojo(v1.6)  data grid which have checkbox to select rows as left most column.  I need to have header column of these checkbox as  delete button instead of Select All checkbox. On clicking the delete button  all selected rows gets deleted.

Please find the [Data grid Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/3NG4f/).

I don’t know how to bring the header column of checkbox as button.  Please help me to customize the widget.
Here is grid js code

```
dojo.ready(function(){
    /*set up data store*/
    var data = {
      identifier: 'id',
      items: []
    };
    var data_list = [
      { col1: "normal", col2: false, col3: 'But are not followed by two hexadecimal', col4: 29.91},
      { col1: "important", col2: false, col3: 'Because a % sign always indicates', col4: 9.33},
      { col1: "important", col2: false, col3: 'Signs can be selectively', col4: 19.34}
    ];
    var rows = 10;
    for(var i=0, l=data_list.length; i<rows; i++){
      data.items.push(dojo.mixin({ id: i+1 }, data_list[i%l]));
    }
    var store = new dojo.data.ItemFileWriteStore({data: data});

    /*set up layout*/
    var layout = [
        { type: "dojox.grid._CheckBoxSelector" },
        [
          {'name': 'Column 1', 'field': 'id', 'width': '20%'},
          {'name': 'Column 2', 'field': 'col2', 'width': '20%'},
          {'name': 'Column 3', 'field': 'col3', 'width': '25%'},
          {'name': 'Column 4', 'field': 'col4', 'width': '20%'}
        ]
    ];
    /*create a new grid:*/
    var grid = new dojox.grid.DataGrid({
        id: 'grid',
        store: store,
        structure: layout,
        cellOverClass: 'cellover'
      },
      document.createElement('div')
    );
    /*append the new grid to the div*/
    dojo.byId("gridDiv").appendChild(grid.domNode);
    /*Call startup() to render the grid*/
    grid.startup();
});
```

HTML

```
<div id="gridDiv"></div>
```

Comment: Might not be exactly what you want, but you can look into grids headerMenu attribute.

Comment: @tik27 Are you mentioning `dojox.grid.EnhancedGrid` in this case with menu plugins? I am using normal `dojox.grid.dataGrid`. Can you please post reference link of grids headerMenu attribute?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can implement your own CheckBoxSelector from the existing one. I discovered the methods by looking at the `_Selector.js` source. The interesting methods to override were `generateHtml` and `doclick`.

See [updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/RichAyotte/eCfXM/6/).

```
    dojo.declare('my.grid._CheckBoxSelector', [dojox.grid._CheckBoxSelector], {
    _headerBuilderClass: dojo.extend(function (view) {
        dojox.grid._HeaderBuilder.call(this, view);
    }, dojox.grid._HeaderBuilder.prototype, {
        generateHtml: function () {
            var w = this.view.contentWidth || 0;
            return '<table style="width:' + w + 'px;" ' +
                'border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" ' +
                'role="presentation"><tr><th style="text-align: center;">' +
                '<button data-dojo-type="dijit.form.Button" type="button">x</button><div class="dojoxGridCheckSelector dijitReset dijitInline dijitCheckBox" style="display:none"></div></th></tr></table>';
        },
        doclick: function (e) {
            this.view.grid.removeSelectedRows();
            return true;
        }
    })
});
```

And

```
/*set up layout*/
    var layout = [{
        type: "my.grid._CheckBoxSelector"
    },

    ...

    }]];
```

To delete the rows

```
    this.view.grid.removeSelectedRows();
```

You can parse the grid after startup to create the dijit widgets.

```
grid.startup();
// Not the best practice here but it should give you a starting point
// on where to find the header node.
dojo.parser.parse(grid.views.views[0].headerContentNode);
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. Can you please explain brief on what was done here? I mean working of `generateHtml` and `doclick` method. How header column is triggering `doclick` method? I have implemented [delete](http://jsfiddle.net/eCfXM/2/) also, but it have error first time  calling `deselectAll` method. If we delete two rows from middle of grid, the grid is not deselecting all rows on calling `deselectAll` method.

Comment: I discovered the `removeSelectedRows` function and it works better than doing it manually. Parsing for the button has also been implemented. See updated answer and fiddle.

Comment: On clicking the checkbox, I am getting error in firebug console as `TypeError: node is null`. May I know the reason for this error?

Comment: It's a harmless but annoying error. You can restore the `<div class="dojoxGridCheckSelector dijitReset dijitInline dijitCheckBox" style="display:none">` element to satisfy the widget. Fiddle updated.

Comment: Can I do selecting row only by clicking the checkbox? As of now an row click also trigger as row is selected.

Comment: Probably but I think we're getting outside the scope of the original question.