# Dojo Datagrid Sorting Mask

Tags: javascript, sorting, datagrid, dojo

I'm currently working with a dojo datagrid that works perfectly well except for one small problem. Due to a large number of fields that must be accounted for, clicking on a column to sort the contents of the grid by the value within that column can be rather time consuming (several seconds). Is there any way to display to my users that the content of the grid is "loading"/"sorting"/etc during this downtime? I've looked around the web but only found loading masks and no sorting masks. As far as I can tell there are no built-in methods for detecting sorting or changes in sorting.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

This Post handles the onHeaderCellClick event which would catch the onClick in the header.
[Declarative dojox.grid.datagrid's header has onclick event?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15893300/declarative-dojox-grid-datagrids-header-has-onclick-event)

Theres a fiddle in the Post, which disrcibes it very well.

You can use it to make a loadingimage visible and hide it again, when sortig ends.

Regards, Miriam